# Accept specific word but negate if you have another specific word together

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I know that I can negate a specific word with negative lookahead - so in my example how do I negate an actual "/checkout/payment" but accept only when have the word "/checkout/"?

What I need exactly:
/itempage/ - not match 
/product/model - not match
**/checkout/** - match
**/checkout/shipping** - match 
/checkout/payment - not match

Comment: [The Greatest Regex Trick Ever - simplified](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1443752647-The-Greatest-Regex-Trick-Ever-%28Simplified%29)

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear enough to get a definite handle on what you want. But in Javascript:

```
/^\/checkout\/(?!payment)/
```

This will match `/checkout/`, `/checkout/shipping`, `/checkout/other`, but not `/checkout/payment` or `/checkout/paymentABC`.